# Odd Error Message Given

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know the error message speaks for itself but I'm just having a problem undestanding it. Is it possible someone can explain it to me as to why I might be getting a message like this.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to private method Users_model::insert_session() from context 'Auth' in   
<b>/home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/application/libraries/auth.php</b> on line <b>281</b><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you tried to access a private method outside of the class. if you want to call `insert_session` from outside the class make it public.
more detailed info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code on line 281, and the method `insert_session()`?

If I read it at first glance, you are calling a `private` method from a class `Auth` which is not in the `private` scope. Try defining `insert_session()` as `protected` and see if your error persists.